# Vue-router push to Named View

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, vue-router

I can't find solution to go to named view. My routes ,

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  children : [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: 'home'
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      components: {
        home : Home,
        contact : Contact,
        geo : Geo,
        shake : Shake,
        camera : Camera
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

]

This is my app.vue

```
...
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button @click="page()">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
...

export default {
    name : 'App',
    methods: {
        page() {
            this.$router.push('home');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to go to the Camera component when I click camera icon/button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you define your `<router-view></router-view>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define multiple router views for each name in named views. There should be one default, and multiple others for each name. Like this.

```
<router-view></router-view>
<router-view name="home"></router-view>
<router-view name="contact"></router-view>
```

All respective components will all be loaded in `router-view` when a url is hit.

You can read more about it in [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views) doc. An see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/posva/6du90epg/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was forgetting about that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect using the script you can try this to change the route.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'your_route_name' })
```

in addition, you can also send params to that route by enabling `props: true` while defining routes,

```
this.$router.push({name: 'your_route_name', params: { var_name: data } })
```